# Typescript create new instance in class

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
///<reference path="HtmlElementsAction.ts" />
///<reference path="DesktopSocket.ts" />

 module Pong {
        export class webPage extends HtmlElementsAction {
            private socket;

            constructor() {
                super();
                this.socket = new DesktopSocket(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've this code.

When I'm executing it, in browser's console is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Error is on new `DesktopSocket(this);`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common error. Check the order of your script tags or if compiling with "out" the order of arguments to tsc.